# How should I code OnStop of a windows service?

Tags: .net, windows-services, startup, restart, shutdown

I have to code a Windows service, but I'm not sure about how to implement the stop of the service.

[OnStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop.aspx)'s documentation does not specify if I should let the ServiceBase instance in a consistent state or it's equivalent to a Dispose: will a new instance of the service be initialized on restart (like most unix services) or the same instance will be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows service is basically a background process.  Once it exits, all of the memory and system resources associated with the process are released.  Restarting the service initializes a brand new instance.

If your service has nothing that strictly requires cleaning up, the OnStop method can be left blank.  However, it is a good place to perform orderly shutdowns of things that need it, e.g., closing files, closing database connections, terminating socket connections, etc.

Comment: The point is that I have to do a few cleanups that the OnStart cannot revert. I'm wondering if I have to refactor the service so that the sequence OnStart(); OnStop(); OnStart() on an instance would work.